# How to do bootstrap carousel slide image fit to display in html and css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to achieve carousel image fit to all kind of display resolution. Currently it does not fit any display resolution. 
How to do bootstrap for carousel image slide that fit to displays

I have recorded my screen, that will show image is not fitted to display 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QsUimIBhuIDYuTwbJtdZgx4CJUeuKwL5/view?usp=sharing

Here is the code i used

```js
/*
   
   Table Of Content
   
   1. Preloader
   2. Smooth Scroll
   3. Scroll Naviagation Background Change with Sticky Navigation
   4. Mobile Navigation Hide or Collapse on Click
   5. Scroll To Top
   6. Tooltip
   7. Ajaxchimp for Subscribe Form
   8. Portfolio Filtering
   9. Magnific Popup
  10. Testimonial Carousel/Slider
  11. Statistics Counter
 

*/


(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        
       /* Preloader */
  
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('.preloader').delay(800).fadeOut('slow');
        });
  
  
  
       /* Smooth Scroll */

        $('a.smoth-scroll').on("click", function (e) {
            var anchor = $(this);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50
            }, 1000);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
  


       
       /* Scroll Naviagation Background Change with Sticky Navigation */
   
        $(window).on('scroll', function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('.header-top-area').addClass('navigation-background');
            } else {
                $('.header-top-area').removeClass('navigation-background');
            }
        });
  
  
  
  
       /* Mobile Navigation Hide or Collapse on Click */
  
        $(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse.in', function (e) {
            if ($(e.target).is('a') && $(e.target).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle') {
                $(this).collapse('hide');
            }
        });
        $('body').scrollspy({
            target: '.navbar-collapse',
            offset: 195
        
   });
   
  
  
  
        /* Scroll To Top */
  
        $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 500) {
            $('.scroll-to-top').fadeIn();
         } else {
            $('.scroll-to-top').fadeOut();
         }
    });
 
 
     $('.scroll-to-top').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
    return false;
     });
  

        
        /* Tooltip */
         
         $(function () {
           $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
           })
     
   
        
        /* Ajaxchimp for Subscribe Form */
  
         $('#mc-form').ajaxChimp();
     
     
  
  
        /* Portfolio Filtering */

        $('.portfolio-inner').mixItUp();


       
        /* Magnific Popup */

        $('.portfolio-popup').magnificPopup({
            type: 'image',
   
            gallery: { enabled: true },
   zoom: { enabled: true,
           duration: 500
     
          },
    
    
         image:{
               markup: '<div class="mfp-figure portfolio-pop-up">'+
               '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
               '<div class="mfp-img"></div>'+
               '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar portfolio_title">'+
               '<div class="mfp-title"></div>'+
               '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>'+
               '</div>'+
               '</div>',

               titleSrc:function(item){
                return item.el.attr('title');
              }
            }
    
    
          });
    
   
        /* Testimonial Carousel/Slider */

        $(".testimonial-carousel-list").owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            autoPlay: true,
            stopOnHover: false,
            navigation: true,
            navigationText: ["<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-left fa-2x owl-navi'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-right fa-2x owl-navi'></i>"],
            itemsDesktop: [1199, 1],
            itemsDesktopSmall: [980, 1],
            itemsTablet: [768, 1],
            itemsTabletSmall: false,
            itemsMobile: [479, 1],
            autoHeight: true,
            pagination: false,
            transitionStyle : "fadeUp"
        });
  
  
  
  
        /* Statistics Counter */
  
        $('.statistics').appear(function() {
           var counter = $(this).find('.statistics-count');
           var toCount = counter.data('count');
      
           $(counter).countTo({
           from: 0,
           to: toCount,
           speed: 5000,
           refreshInterval: 50
           })
           });
              
     
            });

   })(jQuery);
```

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1:before {
  background: #ddd;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
h1:before {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
  

    
    <!-- Meta Tag -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    
    

    
    
    <!------stylesheet-------->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   


    
    
    <!-- All CSS Plugins -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/plugin.css">
    
    <!-- Main CSS Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    
   
</head>
  
  <body>
  

    
    <!-- Home Section Start -->
    <section class="home-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row"></div>
        </div>
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <!-- Indicators -->
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  </ol>

                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
               <div class="item active">
                  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522206038088-8698bcefa6a0?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=4354213f9cd443e781a20faca346d279&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="First slide">
                    <div class="carousel-caption"> 
                   
               </div>
        
               <div class="item">
                  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522205419828-f5b336fc3931?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=7b10bf52b7ea50de3250fe021944e57d&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" >
                  
               </div>
    
               <div class="item">
                  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505765050516-f72dcac9c60e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=74c51a189ca1ab912a127122cf6ba45f&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="Third slide">
                
               </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div> 
    </section>
        <!-- Home Section End -->
            
   
    <!-- Footer End -->
    
    <!-- All Javascript Plugins  -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
      
  </body>

  
 
 
 </html>
```

I am using three images in for carousel slide effect and It scrolls horizontally. Images slide automatically but its does fit to any of devices.

Comment: You code snippet is not running. First fix it and make it runnable.

Comment: show your issue in fiddle

Comment: @NightRyder now updated my code, check it out

Comment: @VicJordan now updated my code, check it out

Comment: Do you want to make the carousel container responsively fit to all screen sizes?

Comment: @PetIbaño yes, it should fit for all screen sizes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the carousel container to fit in different screen sizes. I suggest using CSS unit: `vh` to set your height like this:

```
.carousel-container-selector {
    height: 100vh;
    // min-height: 300px; // you can also set the min/max height as final touch
    // max-height: 1000px; 
}
```

This tells the css to use device/screen height as the height of the carousel.

If you're trying to make the images fit inside the carousel, I suggest you choose between `contain` or `cover`

```
.slide-images-selector {
     width: 100%;
     object-fit: contain; // or cover, check out the difference
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Now image is gets shrink

Comment: Check [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/) out for more object-fit options.

Comment: I suggest you use `cover` for the images, and add `min-height` to the carousel container

Answer (score 5):

Use object-fit css property for the image. Set it to cover

```
object-fit:cover;
```

Comment: still images aren't fitted display

Comment: Hey , I have updated question can you check it out that

Answer (score 1):

Use this css.

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

You can change the height to your need.